# How to display an array of objects using python flask and mongoalchemy

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, flask, mongoalchemy

How to write an end point which will return a array of json objects for mongoalchemy

I am trying to do as shown below:

```
@authenticate_bp.route('/users',methods=['GET'])
def user_list():
    users = [x.serialize for x in TokenBasedAuth.query.all()]
    return jsonify({'usersList': users})
```

the schema is as shown below

```
    class TokenBasedAuth(db.Document):
    username = db.StringField()
    password = db.StringField()
    email = db.StringField()
    firstName = db.StringField()
    lastName = db.StringField()

def serialize(g):
    return {
        "_id" : str(g._id),
        "username" : g.username,
        "firstName" : g.firstName,
        "lastName" : g.lastName,
        "password" : g.password,
        "email" : g.email
    }
```

and the data in db i as shown below

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("586a0f01558b6728388161be"), 
    "username" : "sam", 
    "firstName" : "sam", 
    "lastName" : "123", 
    "password" : "123", 
    "email" : "email@123"
}
```

I am getting error as shown below

AttributeError: 'TokenBasedAuth' object has no attribute 'serialize' // Werkzeug Debugger

Alternate route which is working as expected is as shown below

```
@authenticate_bp.route('/users/list')
def users_listItr():
    try:
        users =  TokenBasedAuth.query.all()
        formatted_users=[]
        for user in users:
            print user
            formatted_users.append({
                'username':user.username,
                'password':user.password,
                'email':user.email,
                'firstName':user.firstName,
                'lastName':user.lastName

            })
        return json.dumps({'users':formatted_users}),
        200,{'Content-Type':'application/json'}

    except Exception,e:
        return jsonify(status='ERROR',message=str(e))
```

But this is not a good idea as i am trying built the api for a schema which might contain few thousand documents with much more complex structure please suggest a way to go about it please

Please help in getting the array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion is to use a generator on the result set with a function to serialize the result object to valid JSON:

```
def serialize(row):
    return {
        "_id" : str(row._id),
        "username" : row.username,
        "firstName" : row.firstName,
        "lastName" : row.lastName,
        "password" : row.password,
        "email" : row.email
    } 

@authenticate_bp.route('/users',methods=['GET'])
def user_list():
    users = [serialize(x) for x in TokenBasedAuth.query.all()]
    return jsonify({'usersList': users})
```

There are some ways you can try to create a custom JSON encoder: [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable). Generally speaking I've found, for Flask, if I need to JSONify something I need to stick to lists and dicts as it is much simpler.

Comment: TypeError: <app.model.authModel.TokenBasedAuth object at 0x02CEE130> is not JSON serializable i am getting the same error

Comment: do you need the "_id" field?

Comment: yes i need _id field that is one i am using as unqiue identifier

Comment: i tried this return json.dumps(json.loads(jsonpickle.encode(users)), indent=2) but i am getting of unwanted fileds like
  {
    "py/object": "app.model.authModel.TokenBasedAuth", 
    "partial": false, 
    "_Document__extra_fields_orig": {},}

Comment: k if dont need _id then how can i do it please help

Comment: do you know how to access the id value from the id object?

Comment: i'm making a guess based on [the docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html) that you can use the `str()` method to get the ID from the ObjectId object. and since your other field are all String this seems like it should work (updated answer)